# How to insert a pointer to the cities array into the towns array in sorted order by town value?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm certain that I'm using pointer syntax incorrectly inside of my insertTowns function because when I try to run my file I just get a segmentation fault when I uncomment the lines involving pointers in that function.  I know that I have the function set up right logically just not syntactically. What am I doing wrong in my pointer syntax for insertTowns?

To keep things simple, assume there is nothing wrong with FILE * infile and the arrays have been malloc'd correctly in a separate file.  Also, length is initialized to 0 and then passed into the readFile function from main in another .c file. So it's not an array out of bounds problem.

I've watched numerous youtube videos on pointers (thenewboston had some good videos), looked at http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/ and a few other resources.

I've provide a snippet of my code below rather than the whole program to keep it simple since it's just a syntax problem:

```
typedef struct cityStruct { unsigned int zip; char * town; } city;
typedef struct zipTownsStruct {
    int * zips;     // indexs to main array cities sorted by zip
    city * * towns; // pointers to main array cities sorted by town name
    city * cities;  // main array of cities in order from file not sorted
} zipTowns;

extern void insertTowns(zipTowns arrs, int * length) {
    int j = (*length) - 1;
    while (j >= 0 && ((strcmp(arrs.towns[j]->town, arrs.cities[*length].town)) > 0)) {
        *arrs.towns[j + 1] = *arrs.towns[j];
        j--;
    }
    *arrs.towns[j + 1] = arrs.cities[*length]; 
}

extern void readFile(zipTowns arrs, FILE * infile, int * length) {
    char * zipCode;
    char * town;
    if((zipCode = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(errno);
    }
    if((town = malloc(sizeof(char) * 26)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(errno);
    }
    while(fscanf(infile,"%s %s", zipCode, town) == 2) {
        arrs.cities[*length].zip = atoi(zipCode);
        arrs.cities[*length].town = town; 
        insertZips(arrs, length);
        insertTowns(arrs, length);
        (*length)++;
    }
    free(zipCode);
    free(town);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in

```
extern void insertTowns(zipTowns arrs, int * length) {
    int j = (*length) - 1;
    while (j >= 0 && ((strcmp(arrs.towns[j]->town, arrs.cities[*length].town)) > 0)) {
        *arrs.towns[j + 1] = *arrs.towns[j];
        j--;
    }
    *arrs.towns[j + 1] = arrs.cities[*length]; 
}
```

if *length* is the number of entries of *arrs.towns* you start with `j = (*length) - 1` so `j+1 == *length` and `*arrs.towns[j + 1]` access out of the array with undefined behavior. Probably the same in `arrs.cities[*length]`, it seems also strange to copy always the same city.

In an array of *length* elements the valid indexes are `0 .. length-1`

---

Warning

```
zipCode = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5)
```

allows to store *zipcode* of 4 characters max to have the place for the ending null character (in France zipcode uses 5 characters, may be not the case for you, but you do not give enough information allowing us to know)

---

It is difficult to say more because you do not give [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We have 5 characters for zipcode in our area as well.  I changed it to zipCode = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6) to account for the terminating null character.  Thanks for catching that.  Regarding the *length, length is initialized to 0 in main and then passed into the function readFile so that shouldn't be the issue.  I might be able to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example but I have 2 .c files, a .h file, a makefile, and a .txt file for a sample file with towns and zipcodes.  How would I go about posting all that code?

Comment: There's something wrong with all of the lines that involve pointers in my insertTowns function. The program runs fine with those lines commented out.